# commas_linter does not work in lintr

Tags: r, coding-style, lint

I am using lintr to ensure my code meets good R style guidelines, but for some reason, the commas_linter does not catch it when I do not put a space after a comma if there is a blank line preceding the erroneous line. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in the package?

Here's a MWE

file: **Test.r**

```
#random comment

a <- c(4,5)
b = 7
```

Then, I run the following:

```
lintr::lint("./Test.r", linters = list(spacesAfterCommas = commas_linter, 
                                       useArrowForAssignments = assignment_linter))
```

The only error I get is the following:

```
./Test.r:4:3: style: Use <-, not =, for assignment.
b = 7
  ^
```

Why is the commas_linter not catching my error?

Comment: so you get two errors if you delete the blank line?

Comment: Yep! It works fine if the line is removed. I do like to put spaces between my code chunks though and then that makes this fail.

Comment: i cant get it to recognize with any preceding comments, blank lines or not. seems like a bug, I don't see why it wouldn't work. and the result of `get_source_expressions('./test.r')` is too much for me to go through right now

Comment: Thanks for checking other sources of failures. I'll file a bug report with the package maintainer.

Comment: Curiously, this question seems to be the easiest to find example on proper use of `linters` argument - ie. it requires a list with *named* items.